# Angular2 - Adding modal open to body tag

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am using Modals with angular2 and bootstrap. I am no longer using JQuery to open a modal and I now have a problem in that the "modal-open" class is no longer attached to the body tag.

I use this class to remove the background scroller using:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

What is the simplest way to add "modal-open" to the body tag using NG2?

Many thanks!

Comment: you mean dynamically ? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass

Comment: Yes, but to the "body" tag... I don't think this will work for anything in the index.html file...?

Comment: How about using a native Bootstrap 4 + Angular 2+ integration that does it for you? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal

Comment: I want to avoid installing libraries where possible to preserve page size... I did think of installing it though.